# Issue with extending class in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I saw some extension files which are in TYPO3 4.5. (`class.tx_ajaxsearch_pi1.php`...), looks like this way:

```
class tx_ajaxsearch_pi1 extends tslib_pibase {
...
if (defined('TYPO3_MODE') && $TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/ajax_search/pi1/class.tx_ajaxsearch_pi1.php']) {
    include_once($TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/ajax_search/pi1/class.tx_ajaxsearch_pi1.php']);
}
```

I am checking this document about `XCLASS`: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.1.0/view/3/8/

Questions:

1. According to this document: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.1.0/view/3/8/

   Extending TYPO3s PHP classes is recommended mostly for special needs in individual projects. This is due to the limitation that a class can only be extended once. Thus, if many extensions try to extend the same class, only one of them will succeed and in turn the others will not function correctly.

But why class `tslib_pibase` can be extended many times by different extension classes?

2. Is it a good habit to put below codes in every extension scripts? Just in case the extension class needs to be extended in the future?

```
    if (defined('TYPO3_MODE') && $TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/ajax_search/pi1/class.tx_ajaxsearch_pi1.php']) {
            include_once($TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/ajax_search/pi1/class.tx_ajaxsearch_pi1.php']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCLASS'ing is an approach, when someone substitutes one class with another one. Sounds like inheritance in OOP, but in fact it is different, because you can **XCLASS only once**, since in TYPO3 global scope one class definition is substituted with another one.

So, i.e. you XCLASS t3lib_db with ux_t3lib_db - that means, taht t3lib_db will never be used in DB processing, but ux_t3lib_db

Sure, your XCLASS can extend the base class, like `ux_t3lib_db extends t3lib_db`, so it works with inheritance of OOP, but if someone else would like to XCLASS t3lib_db too this will fail simply because TYPO3 will not find t3lib_db in it's scope, because it is already substituted with ux_t3lib_db. So, the only winner will be the one, who XCLASS'ed first.

You can read more [here](http://wiki.typo3.org/XCLASS).

But, general note is, that **XCLASS'ing is the last option** you should try. Use [hooks](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Hooks/Index.html) or [signals/slots](http://blog.tolleiv.de/2011/11/signal-slots-in-extbase/) (last works in ExtBase only).

Answering your second question, I can say, that yes, you can do this in 4.5, but no - you shouldn't do that from 6.0.